# Where can we specify THROW_ON_OVERLOADED=true in the Datastax java-driver?

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

On the cassandra.apache website we talk about a way to improve back pressure. (https://cassandra.apache.org/blog/Improving-Apache-Cassandras-Front-Door-and-Backpressure.html)

It is related to CASSANDRA-15013. There they talk about a setting THROW_ON_OVERLOADED which should be set to true, in order for the node to throw OverloadedException.

How/Where can we set the THROW_ON_OVERLOADED property with the DataStax java-driver?

Answer (score 2):

I've noted that you've asked the same question on https://community.datastax.com/questions/11741/ so I'm re-posting my answer here.

The Java driver won't be adopting `THROW_ON_OVERLOAD` as a startup option but instead gracefully handle the backpressure in [JAVA-2589](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/JAVA-2589) when it gets implemented.

The idea is for the driver to stop sending requests when Netty's `Channel#isWritable()` returns false and wait for `channelWritabilityChanged()` before sending requests again.

This means that configuring the client startup option will not be required. Cheers!